# Autocomplete box on select value not giving ID

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, box

Hi I m working with spring mvc.I have created a code for search by keyword for autocomplete box to search the value from database.I have used the ajax call to call the service from controller.From that i got the list in dropdown.But what i want is on select the value in autocomplete box it will take the id of that value and call the another method on controller which gives the detail from that id and print on jsp page in different fields.

This is my jsp page code:

```
    <script>
    function doAjax() {

        var dataToBeSent = {
            keyword : document.getElementById("tags").value,
            godownID : "3",
        };
        $(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url : "itemByName",
                data : dataToBeSent,
                type : "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(response) {
                    //alert("success");
                    var data1 = JSON.stringify(response);

                    var obj = JSON.parse(data1);

                    var availableTags = [];

                    var mn;

                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                        alert("Length:" + obj.length);

                        alert = ("in for loop");

                        mn = [ obj[i].ItemIDP, obj[i].ItemName ];

                        alert = ("mn");

                        availableTags[i] = obj[i].ItemName;

                        //  availableTags[i] = obj[i].ItemIDP;

                    }

                    $("#tags").autocomplete(
                            {

                                source : function(request, response) {
                                    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                                            availableTags, request.term);

                                    response(results.slice(0, 10));
                                }
                            });

                    $("#tags").autocomplete({
                        autoFocus : true

                    });

                },

                error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("errorThrown");
                }

            });

        });

    }
</script>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <h5>Medicine</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                                            <input id="tags" class="form-control input-mg"
                                                onkeyup="doAjax()" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
```